# Google Test return value

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm using Google Test and Google Mock frameworks for a project's unit tests. I have various unit tests projects and want to automate my build so to run all of them.

I was expecting the unit tests executable to return 0 on success and 1 (or any other value) on any test failure, but I'm getting 1 when all tests passed. I'm getting some GMOCK warnings but couldn't find any documentation about warnings affecting return value.

I tried running the tests filtering to run just one test case where no GMOCK warnings are triggered and still get 1 as return value.

I had a couple of DISABLED test cases, so I commented them out. Still getting 1 as return value.

According to documentation and code comments for `RUN_ALL_TESTS` macro, the return value should be 0.

I can't think of anything else causing return value 1. Am I missing anything?

Comment: BTW: I'm not using the return value of the unit testing executable to check for failures, but scan the (XML) test reports for occurrence of 'failure'.

Comment: I wouldn't expect Gmock warnings to affect the return value of `RUN_ALL_TESTS()`.  What warnings specifically do you get?  Can you put up a small test case which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the definition of the `RUN_ALL_TESTS()` macro from gtest.h there's clearly stated that 0 is returned on no failures:

```
// Use this macro in main() to run all tests.  It returns 0 if all
// tests are successful, or 1 otherwise.
//
// RUN_ALL_TESTS() should be invoked after the command line has been
// parsed by InitGoogleTest().

#define RUN_ALL_TESTS()\
  (::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->Run())
```

Appearantly even warnings (from gmock) may result in a return value of 1. Try what happens if you get rid of the gmock warnings (e.g. using s.th. like NiceMock<> to wrap your mock class instance).

Comment: Getting rid of the mock warnings is not so easy, hence my question :) I edited it so to make it clear.